# Expected /...path.../projects_users.rb to define Projects_users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, model, seed

What I'm trying to do is to create posts in a relational table called 'projects_users' with the seed, but after a 'rake db:seed' the following error is thrown:

```
Expected /...path.../projects_users.rb to define Projects_users
```

**projects_users.rb:**

```
class ProjectsUsers < ActiveRecord::Base
    // no code yet
end
```

('projects_users' has a controller and view too (also not used))

**projects_users table:**

```
project_id
user_id
```

**projects model:**

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users, :class_name => 'User'
  belongs_to :user

  has_many :tickets, :dependent => :destroy

  attr_accessible :user_id, :title, :description, :start_date, :end_date
end
```

**users model:**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, :email, :password

  has_and_belongs_to_many :projects
  has_many :tickets

  before_save :create_remember_token

  def create_remember_token
    self.remember_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  end

end
```

**seeds.rb:**

```
pu5 = Projects_users.create(:user_id => 12, :project_id => 6)
```

What does the error mean and how do I fix this?

Comment: try `pu5 = ProjectsUsers.create(:user_id => 12, :project_id => 6)`. But anyway its not a good idea as I mentioned in other question. You should use `has_many :through` for such cases. for reference go through http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has_many-through-and-has_and_belongs_to_many . This will help you understand the difference. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model must be singular. You need to rename your model from **projects_users.rb** to **projects_user.rb**
Also the class definition should say:

```
class ProjectsUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  // no code yet
end
```

So in your seeds file you should be making a call to it like this:

```
pu5 = ProjectsUser.create(:user_id => 12, :project_id => 6)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I changed the name to Projects_user as you suggested, but now I get the following error instead: "uninitialized constant ProjectsController::Projects_user". Do you know what that means?

Comment: Please post the contents of your projects_controller file. Anywhere you might have `Projects_user` - should say `ProjectsUser`

Comment: I removed the underscore and that did the trick! Thanks a lot!